# Cannot Add Dynamically Generated Textbox's Text To A List (C#)

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Mod
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int c = 0;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
            txtRun.Name = "txtDynamic" + c++;
            txtRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 18 + (20 * c));
            txtRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200,15);
            this.Controls.Add(txtRun);
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string>tilelocation = List<string>();
            tilelocation.Add();  //What goes in this method's arguments?
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code.  Button1 creates a theoretically infinite # of textboxes, but I wish to add the text in these dynamically generated textboxes to a list.  How can this be done?
[EDIT]
And how can I display them all in a messagebox, each on separate lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I wish to add the text in these dynamically generated textboxes to
>   a list. How can this be done?

You should use `new List<string>` like:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> tilelocation = new List<string>();
    foreach(TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(r=> r.Name.StartsWith("txtDynamic"))
          titlelocation.Add(tb.Text);

 //if you want a string out of it. 

 string str = string.Join(",", titlelocation);
 MessageBox.Show(str);
}
```

EDIT: For each text on new line use:

```
string str = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, titlelocation);
MessageBox.Show(str);
```

Comment: Then it says, "It's a type, but used like a variable."  (TextBox)

Comment: Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Forms.TextBox>' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' <--There is the exact error.

Comment: @user2351094, my bad, just copied your code, forgot the new keyword. It should be `new List<TextBox>()`

Comment: Thanks!  Also, if I wish to display this all in a MessageBox, how would I use a foreach statement to do so?

Comment: @user2351094, I completely messed up my answer, read your question again. I have updated my answer, I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: string.Join, I need to get my coffee

Comment: Sorry, one more thing.  I updated the question.  How would I make them on separate lines, I forgot the syntax.

Comment: @user2351094, in `string.Join` replace `","`, with Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a reference to the control.

The other secret is that you have to keep it in the ViewState so it's available between post backs.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  int c = 0;
  private List<TextBox _lstTextBoxList;
  public List<TextBox> lstTextBoxList {
    get { 
      if(_lstTextBoxList == null) {
        _lstTextBoxList = ViewState["lstTextBoxList"] as List<TextBox>;
      }
      return _lstTextBoxList; 
    }
    set { ViewState["lstTextBoxList"] = _lstTextBoxList = value; }
  }


  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    TextBox txtRun = new TextBox();
    txtRun.Name = "txtDynamic" + c++;
    txtRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 18 + (20 * c));
    txtRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200,15);
    this.Controls.Add(txtRun);
    lstTextBoxList.Add(txtRun);
  }
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Not sure of your goal here:
    List<string> tilelocation = List<string>();
    tilelocation.Add(lstTextBoxList[lstTextBoxList.Count - 1]);
    // I would assume you wanted this:
    List<string> strValues = lstTextBoxList.Select<TextBox,string>(t =>   t.Text).ToList();
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to use a seperate button2 click event to add the text. Why don't you use a global variable tilelocation, and add the text to this list in the button1_click event? Something like：

```
txtRun.Text=Your Text;
tilelocation.add(Your Text);
```

If you want to display them in a message box, then add codes：

```
string str="";
foreach(text in tilelocation)
{
   str+=text;
}
MessageBox.Show(str);
```

Comment: I want it to add the text AND display them all in a messagebox.